# Unable to find longest common prefix of a perfectly working code (escape or special characters issue)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace

I have a problem where I want to [find the longest common prefix of N strings given in an array](https://www.interviewbit.com/blog/longest-common-prefix/).

Below is a perfectly working code:

```
def longestCommonPrefix(S) :
    if (len(S) == 0):
        return ""
    for i in range(len(S[0])):
        c = S[0][i]
        for j in range(len(S)):
            if (i == len(S[j]) or S[j][i] != c):
                return S[0][0:i];             
    return S[0]

X = ["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt anim id est laborum.",
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod td exercitation ullamcon reprehenderit int occaecat cupidatat nonmollit anim id est laborum.",
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, ccaecat cupidatat nonmollit anim id est laborum.",
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adrit int occaecat cupidatat nonmollit anim id est laborum."]

print(longestCommonPrefix(X))

>> 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ad'
```

**PROBLEM**: When I have my text array as:

```
X = [
'Class- VII-CBSE-Mathematics\\nIntegers\ne EMBIBE\nThe temperature at Srinagar \\( =-2^{\\circ} \\mathrm{C} \\)\nTherefore, the difference \\( =-2^{\\circ} \\mathrm{C}-\\left(-8^{\\circ} \\mathrm{C}\\right) \\) \\( =6^{\\circ} \\mathrm{C} \\)\n(d) The temperature of Srinagar and Shimla taken together \\( =-2^{\\circ} \\mathrm{C}+5^{\\circ} \\mathrm{C} \\) \\( =3^{\\circ} \\mathrm{C} \\)\nThe temperature at Shimla \\( =5^{\\circ} \\mathrm{C}>3^{\\circ} \\mathrm{C} \\). Therefore the temperature of Srinagar and Shimla taken together is less than that of Shimla.\n\nThe temperature at Srinagar \\( =-2^{\\circ} \\mathrm{C}<3^{\\circ} \\mathrm{C} \\). Therefore, the temperature of Srinagar and Shimla taken together is not less than that of Srinagar',
'Class- VII-CBSE-Mathematics\\nIntegers\ne EMBIBE\nSubmarine floating below the sea level \\( =1200 \\mathrm{~m} \\)\nTherefore, the vertical distance between them \\( =5000+1200 \\)\n\\[\n=6200 \\mathrm{~m}\n\\]',
'Class- VII-CBSE-Mathematics\\nIntegers\ne EMBIBE\n\\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\n\\hline\\( -4 \\) & \\( -3 \\) & \\( -2 \\) \\\\\n\\hline\\( -6 \\) & 4 & \\( -7 \\) \\\\\n\\hline\n\\end{tabular}', '\n(i) Sum of the rows:\n\\[\n\\begin{array}{l}\n5+-1+-4=0 \\\\\n-5+-2+7=0 \\\\\n0+3+-3=0\n\\end{array}\n\\]\nSum of the columns:\n\\[\n\\begin{array}{l}\n5+-5+0=0 \\\\\n-1+-2+3=0 \\\\\n-4+7+-3=0\n\\end{array}\n\\]\nSum of the diagonals:\n\\[\n\\begin{array}{l}\n5+-2+-3=0 \\\\\n-4+-2+0=-6\n\\end{array}\n\\]\nThus, this is not a magic square because all the sums are not equal\n(ii) Sum of the rows:\n\\[\n\\begin{array}{l}\n1+-10+0=-9 \\\\\n-4+-3+-2=-9 \\\\\n-6+4+-7=-9\n\\end{array}\n\\]\nSum of the columns:\n\\[\n\\begin{array}{l}\n1+-4+-6=-9 \\\\\n-10+-3+4=-9 \\\\\n0+-2+-7=-9\n\\end{array}\n\\]\nSum of the diagonals:\n\\[\n\\begin{array}{l}\n1+-3+-7=0 \\\\\n0+-3+-6=-9\n\\end{array}\n\\]\nThus, this is a magic square because all the sums are equal',
'Class- VII-CBSE-Mathematics\\nIntegers\ne EMBIBE\n(ii) \\( a=118, b=125 \\)\n(iii) \\( \\mathrm{a}=75, \\mathrm{~b}=84 \\)\n(iv) \\( a=28, b=11 \\)', '\n\\[\n\\begin{array}{l}\n\\text { LHS } a-(-b)=21-(-18)=39 \\\\\n\\text { RHS } a+b=21+18=39 \\\\\n\\mathrm{LHS}=\\text { RHS }\n\\end{array}\n\\]\nThus verified\n\\[\n\\begin{array}{l}\n\\operatorname{LHS~} a-(-b)=118-(-125)=243 \\\\\n\\text { RHS a }+b=118+125=243 \\\\\n\\mathrm{LHS}=\\text { RHS }\n\\end{array}\n\\]\nThus verified\n\\[\n\\begin{array}{l}\n\\operatorname{LHS~} a-(-b)=75-(-84)=159 \\\\\n\\text { RHS } a+b=75+84=159 \\\\\n\\text { LHS }=\\text { RHS }\n\\end{array}\n\\]\nThus verified\n\\[\n\\begin{array}{l}\n\\operatorname{LHS~} a-(-b)=28-(-11)=39 \\\\\n\\text { RHS } a+b=28+11=39\n\\end{array}\n\\]\n\\[\n\\mathrm{LHS}=\\mathrm{RHS}\n\\]\nThus verified',
'Class- VII-CBSE-Mathematics\\nIntegers\ne EMBIBE\n(c) \\( -7>-29 \\)\n(d) \\( 0<20 \\)\n(e) \\( -101>-159 \\)',
]
```

I get the result as `''` EMPTY string. Can someone please help me with it.

given on the suggestion for the below answer, I also did:

```
def replace(x):
    for i in ["\\","\n","\t",'\"',"\'","\b","\f","\r"]:
        x = x.replace(i,"`")
    return x

X = [replace(i) for i in X]
```

I have also tried doing `X = [repr(i) for i in X]`

But still I get the same `""` answer.

Comment: dont you think you need to modify the perfect working code according to the escape and special characters ?

Comment: @sahasrara62 yeah. Isn't that why I asked the question on "What to do"? I don't even what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is that your list X doesn't contain the number of elements that you think. There are 7 elements (*print(len(X))*). Search for *b=11 \\)', '\n* and you'll see what you've done wrong

Comment: @Cobra thank for letting me know. And then there are people who just want to point out things without even looking at the problem or the code. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 1):

The data are malformed. I've made an assumption about what it should look like by escaping four single-quotes which results in the X list containing 5 elements (which is what I think is expected).

I then implemented the longest common prefix function like this:

```
X = [
    'Class- VII-CBSE-Mathematics\\nIntegers\ne EMBIBE\nThe temperature at Srinagar \\( =-2^{\\circ} \\mathrm{C} \\)\nTherefore, the difference \\( =-2^{\\circ} \\mathrm{C}-\\left(-8^{\\circ} \\mathrm{C}\\right) \\) \\( =6^{\\circ} \\mathrm{C} \\)\n(d) The temperature of Srinagar and Shimla taken together \\( =-2^{\\circ} \\mathrm{C}+5^{\\circ} \\mathrm{C} \\) \\( =3^{\\circ} \\mathrm{C} \\)\nThe temperature at Shimla \\( =5^{\\circ} \\mathrm{C}>3^{\\circ} \\mathrm{C} \\). Therefore the temperature of Srinagar and Shimla taken together is less than that of Shimla.\n\nThe temperature at Srinagar \\( =-2^{\\circ} \\mathrm{C}<3^{\\circ} \\mathrm{C} \\). Therefore, the temperature of Srinagar and Shimla taken together is not less than that of Srinagar',
    'Class- VII-CBSE-Mathematics\\nIntegers\ne EMBIBE\nSubmarine floating below the sea level \\( =1200 \\mathrm{~m} \\)\nTherefore, the vertical distance between them \\( =5000+1200 \\)\n\\[\n=6200 \\mathrm{~m}\n\\]',
    'Class- VII-CBSE-Mathematics\\nIntegers\ne EMBIBE\n\\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\n\\hline\\( -4 \\) & \\( -3 \\) & \\( -2 \\) \\\\\n\\hline\\( -6 \\) & 4 & \\( -7 \\) \\\\\n\\hline\n\\end{tabular}\', \'\n(i) Sum of the rows:\n\\[\n\\begin{array}{l}\n5+-1+-4=0 \\\\\n-5+-2+7=0 \\\\\n0+3+-3=0\n\\end{array}\n\\]\nSum of the columns:\n\\[\n\\begin{array}{l}\n5+-5+0=0 \\\\\n-1+-2+3=0 \\\\\n-4+7+-3=0\n\\end{array}\n\\]\nSum of the diagonals:\n\\[\n\\begin{array}{l}\n5+-2+-3=0 \\\\\n-4+-2+0=-6\n\\end{array}\n\\]\nThus, this is not a magic square because all the sums are not equal\n(ii) Sum of the rows:\n\\[\n\\begin{array}{l}\n1+-10+0=-9 \\\\\n-4+-3+-2=-9 \\\\\n-6+4+-7=-9\n\\end{array}\n\\]\nSum of the columns:\n\\[\n\\begin{array}{l}\n1+-4+-6=-9 \\\\\n-10+-3+4=-9 \\\\\n0+-2+-7=-9\n\\end{array}\n\\]\nSum of the diagonals:\n\\[\n\\begin{array}{l}\n1+-3+-7=0 \\\\\n0+-3+-6=-9\n\\end{array}\n\\]\nThus, this is a magic square because all the sums are equal',
    'Class- VII-CBSE-Mathematics\\nIntegers\ne EMBIBE\n(ii) \\( a=118, b=125 \\)\n(iii) \\( \\mathrm{a}=75, \\mathrm{~b}=84 \\)\n(iv) \\( a=28, b=11 \\)\', \'\n\\[\n\\begin{array}{l}\n\\text { LHS } a-(-b)=21-(-18)=39 \\\\\n\\text { RHS } a+b=21+18=39 \\\\\n\\mathrm{LHS}=\\text { RHS }\n\\end{array}\n\\]\nThus verified\n\\[\n\\begin{array}{l}\n\\operatorname{LHS~} a-(-b)=118-(-125)=243 \\\\\n\\text { RHS a }+b=118+125=243 \\\\\n\\mathrm{LHS}=\\text { RHS }\n\\end{array}\n\\]\nThus verified\n\\[\n\\begin{array}{l}\n\\operatorname{LHS~} a-(-b)=75-(-84)=159 \\\\\n\\text { RHS } a+b=75+84=159 \\\\\n\\text { LHS }=\\text { RHS }\n\\end{array}\n\\]\nThus verified\n\\[\n\\begin{array}{l}\n\\operatorname{LHS~} a-(-b)=28-(-11)=39 \\\\\n\\text { RHS } a+b=28+11=39\n\\end{array}\n\\]\n\\[\n\\mathrm{LHS}=\\mathrm{RHS}\n\\]\nThus verified',
    'Class- VII-CBSE-Mathematics\\nIntegers\ne EMBIBE\n(c) \\( -7>-29 \\)\n(d) \\( 0<20 \\)\n(e) \\( -101>-159 \\)'
]


def lcp(sa):
    assert len(sa) > 1
    k, *r = sa
    for o in range(min(map(len, sa))):
        for e in r:
            if e[o] != k[o]:
                return k[:o]
    return k

print(lcp(X))
```

**Output:**

```
Class- VII-CBSE-Mathematics\nIntegers
e EMBIBE
```

Comment: Oh sh!!. Thank you for letting me know. I got it now. Problem is that I thought starting of the string is same but somehow I inserted extra lines. It was supped to be 5 but there were actuallt 7 strings. After you pointed out, I searched for `', ` and I found out that 2 strings are extra that's why there were always `''` result.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has problem. You are checking character by character and in your string there are escape characters like `\n`, `\t, \b` etc which are handled differently by Python. You can try substituting those in the first place and then compare the strings?

Like `X = [i.replace("\n","$$").replace("\t","--").replace("\b",'##') for i in X]`

One problem would be that your `\begin` would not make sense anymore but you can change that again `string.replace("##','\b')` later.

Comment: But that's not a feasible solution IMO. Doubles the time.